# jquery .on() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an orbit simulation and I'm just trying to add a little user interaction to th mouseenter and mouseexit events. You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/Pe87m/).

My `on` statement is:

```
$('.planet').on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        pauseAnimation = true;
    },
    'mouseleave': function () {
        pauseAnimation = false;
    },
    'click' : function () {
        alert('click');
    }
});
```

but none of the events seem to be triggered. If it matters, I'm using the latest Chrome on a mac.

Comment: That's a lot of code to read. anyway `$().ready(function () {` is deprecated. change to `$(function(){})`

Comment: it's not mouseexit, it's mouseleave. Pretty cool animation!

Comment: @frenchie - I've fixed it, but still has no effect.

Comment: @gdoron - I've made the change.

Comment: It won't fix anything, it's just a comment about best practice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a z-index issue. Add `z-index: 1;` to the `.planet` css section. Fiddle worked fine after that: http://jsfiddle.net/Pe87m/9/

Comment: Interestingly, the animation keeps working so when the mouse leave happens the planets all snap forward.

Comment: I'm curious about that myself. Nothing jumps out at me that would cause that 'snapping'.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Always learning; how did you think about the z-index?

Comment: I've fixed the pause so they don't snap forward. Take a look at the link now.

Comment: @Justin808 Pretty neat I like it.

Comment: @frenchie I've dealt with this particular problem more than once ;)

Comment: @x1a4: ok, now I'll know of another weird place where to look. Thanks.